# Can we declare a function alongside variables in C?

Tags: c, function, nested-function

I recently came across a golf coding<sup>†</sup> question in which I thought of writing a function of type `int` in `main` itself, which could access all variables inside main. But to reduce the number of characters, I thought of writing a function alongside a variable. Something like this :

```
int i,f(){/*function code*/};
```

Can I do this? If Yes/No, then why?

---

<sup>†</sup> Code Golf is a form of recreational programming in which a given challenge must be solved with the shortest possible program. Reducing the number of characters in the source code is the primary objective, maintainability and readability is unimportant. Please consider this objective before commenting.

Comment: There is no language C/C++. Pick one.

Comment: What happens when you try it?

Comment: Please do not even think about doing that (if it its possible or not)!

Comment: With terrabytes of storage space, saving some characters in your **source** code tends to be of very low priority compared to readability.

Comment: @DieterLücking But why?

Comment: @Olaf I mentioned that this was meant for golf coding purpose!

Comment: @SahilArora: Same reason you should not write all your code in a single line.

Comment: That makes my point not less relevant. You first should learn a language completely and be sure what & why you do it a specific way.

Comment: @Olaf if his goal is to write code in order to achieve the absolute fewest possible characters then it is entirely relevant to ask a community of peers if a language supports quirky syntax that is supported elsewhere.

Comment: @SahilArora you can't define a function within `main()` anyway, regardless of how you try to golf it.

Comment: @WeatherVane yeah thanks for that! But the question remains still valid, since I may want to do it globally.

Comment: @SahilArora been there, tried that, no good.

Comment: @WeatherVane You can define a pointer function, as I have in my example.

Comment: Please pick at most one of C and C++. If you want to have an answer for both, ask two questions. That's site policy. Downvoted until you fix this.

Comment: @ArchieGertsman thanks, that's food for thought.

Comment: Of all the justifications for wanting to do this, "to reduce the number of characters" is amongst the dumbest.  The amount to time you might save in your entire life typing fewer characters you have just spent asking this question - they have no impact on compiled code size.  Nested functions are not legal in any case in C++ or C;  they are supported as an extension in GNU C, but not GNU C++ at all.

Comment: @Clifford If OP is doing code golf, saving characters is the goal.

Comment: If your compiler supports nested functions as an extension, this might work.. only one way to find out

Comment: @FUZxxl Thanks Sir for the rescue. I hope some guys haven't here payed a visit to codegolf.stackexchange.com , while I just payed mine!

Comment: @FUZxxl : I have never previously come across the term "code golf" before, and ignored the term in the question - my error.  Had I realised that was the aim and not anything useful I would chosen to ignore this question.  From the comments I am not the only person unfamiliar with the term.  Perhaps the question should be modified to include an explanation or a link?

Comment: @Clifford I tried to add a “code-golf” tag, but said tag is banned as code-golf should be played on [codegolf.se]. I'm adding an explanation right now.

Comment: I originally tried adding the tag, but got the same error, so couldn't add. Also, this is not a code golf question, and I guess, is completely valid for this site.

Comment: @SahilArora: you can't define function inside `main`, but in C++11 you can create a lambda in it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
int i,f(){/*function code*/};
```

In C, no you cannot it is not a valid syntax.

What you can do is this:

```
 int i, f();  /* declare an int i and a function f that returns an int */
```

which is probably not what you want.

Comment: That's neat! Do people actually ever do this? I'd be terribly confused.

Comment: `f()` is a old K&R style and an obsolecent feature. It should generate a warning in properly configured compilers. Use correct prototypes.

Comment: @Olaf no diagnostic required by C99 (as your comment initially put). I tried to stay close to OP code, for people not aware, the non-obsolescent  declaration is: `int i, f(void);`

Comment: Why would you declare a function  along side variables? what's the purpose?

Answer (score 1):

In C, no function can be defined in another function... It is as simple as that.

As you stated,if you want to access main function variables in your sub functions.. Its not possible with formal variables.but, it can achieved by calling by reference i.e, using pointer variables

Comment: @JamesRoot: I would not be sure about that. OP very well seems to think of using that for nexting function declarations. But it might just be a thought or general missconception.

Comment: @JamesRoot the question asked "writing a function of type`int` in `main` itself".

Comment: Ah my bad, I missed that line.

Comment: @Aravol your link says "There is currently no text in this page." ... ah got it - remove the "which" from the link pls.I see that is ref C++ but OP still hasn't picked which language.

Comment: This answer only pertains to C.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @ouah, I've found that you can do this with function pointers as well. Here is an example:

```
int i, (*f)();
f = (int(*)())&i;

cout << f << endl;
```

the output of this would be the address of i.

Comment: Nice, but strictly speaking, this is not C because of cout.

Comment: Ah, well he did include both the c and c++ tags

Comment: This is not supported by ISO C (casting object pointer to function pointer), compilers may implement it as an extension

Answer (score 0):

You can *declare* a function alongside a variable:

```
int fgetc(FILE*), getc(FILE*), errno;
```

but you cannot *define* a function alongside a variable as the production rules for function definitions (cf. ISO 9899:2011 §6.9.1 ¶1) read

```
function-definition:
    declaration-specifiers declarator declaration-list(opt) compound-statement

declaration-list:
    declaration
    declaration-list declaration
```